# How to shorten text posts with read only php

Tags: php, text, strlen

Newbie at PHP here, How do I shorten the text of my blog posts using PHP? So far this is the code that I have but it's not working and I'm not sure where I need to be going from here.

```
 if ($stmt->prepare($sql)) {

                /*bind the parameter onto the query*/
                $stmt->bind_param('i', $postid);
                /* execute statement */
                $stmt->execute();

                /* bind result variables */
                $stmt->bind_result($posttitle, $postdate, $postcontent);


                /* fetch values */
                if ($stmt->fetch()) {
                    if(strlen($postcontent)>10){

                    $postcontent=substr($postcontent,0,20).' Read more';
                    print ("<div class='blogposts'>$posttitle | $postdate</div><br/>\n $postcontent");



                    }

                }
                else{
                    print ("No category name is retrieved. <br/>");
                }} else {
                print ("query failed");
            }
```

Comment: Not working how `Read more` doesn't do anything? Error thrown?

Comment: You are doing the `strlen()`/`substr()` **after** you have already printed the `$postcontent`. Try moving the `if()` to before the `print()`

Comment: What do you mean by shorten the text of my blog posts? Do you mean by removing the end of the string? Or finding synonyms and merging words together to shorten the title? Or a whole third solution?

Comment: Okay heres an update guys, the posts now shorten but I need the "read more" to be a link to the complete post How exactly do I do that?

Updated code to what i currently have

Comment: @Uruloke I mean shorten as in shorten the blog posts to give you a sort of a preview for the post

sorta like this
Blog post text preview here(Read More)

then you would click read more for the entire text

Comment: Then you need to wrap `Read more` with a link -> `<a href="YourLink">Read more</a>`

Comment: Oh, okay thanks guys I think I understand how this is working now. Thanks so much for your help!